# Android Room JUnit testing: "AsyncTask #1" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot perform this operation because there is no current transaction

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, android-room

I'm trying to run simple test to my project but this exception is holding me back and i cannot find out why.

Im doing a simple test to insert some new customers to my database. My first problem i encountered when inserting customers was that I could NOT insert data in the Main Thread so I used an `AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable())` but this time i ran into this problem.

I've provided the following classes that should give a good insight I hope..

**TestClass:**

```
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
public class ExampleUnitTest {
ShopDatabase db;
private CustomerDao customerDao;

@Before
public void createDB() {
    Context context = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext();
    db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, ShopDatabase.class).build();
    customerDao = db.customerDao();
}

@Test
public void createUser(){
    final Customer customer = new Customer("Test", "Test test", Date.valueOf("2020-10-10"));

    AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            customerDao.insert(customer);
        }
    });

    Customer customerFound = customerDao.getCustomerByName("Test", "Test test");
    assertEquals(customerFound.getFirstName(), customer.getFirstName(), "Could not find user..");
}

@After
public void closeDB() {
    db.close();
}
```

**Repository:**

```
public class Repository {

private CustomerDao customerDao;

private LiveData<List<Customer>> allCustomers;

private Customer customer;

public Repository(Application application) {
    // Get DB instance
    ShopDatabase db = ShopDatabase.getInstance(application);

    customerDao = db.customerDao();

    allCustomers = customerDao.getAllCustomers();
}

public void insert(Customer customer) {
    new InsertCustomerAsyncTask(customerDao).execute(customer);
}

public Customer getCustomerByName(String first, String last) {
    return customerDao.getCustomerByName(first, last);
}

public LiveData<List<Customer>> getAllCustomers() {
    return allCustomers;
}

// Inner Async class to insert customers
private static class InsertCustomerAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Customer, Void, Void> {
    private CustomerDao customerDao;

    public InsertCustomerAsyncTask(CustomerDao customerDao) {
        this.customerDao = customerDao;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Customer... customers) {
        customerDao.insert(customers[0]);
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Database:**

```
@Database(entities = {Customer.class}, version = 1)
@TypeConverters({Converters.class})
public abstract class ShopDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
private static ShopDatabase instance;

public abstract CustomerDao customerDao();

public static synchronized ShopDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(), 
ShopDatabase.class,"shop_database")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .addCallback(roomCallback)
                .build();
    }
    return instance;
}

private static RoomDatabase.Callback roomCallback = new RoomDatabase.Callback() {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(@NonNull SupportSQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onCreate(db);
        new PopulateDbAsyncTask(instance).execute();
    }
};

private static class PopulateDbAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private CustomerDao customerDao;

    PopulateDbAsyncTask(ShopDatabase db) {
        customerDao = db.customerDao();
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... voids) {
       // Customers
        long c = customerDao.insert(new Customer("One", "A", Date.valueOf("2019-05-10")));
        long c2 = customerDao.insert(new Customer("Two", "B", Date.valueOf("2020-07-10")));
        long c3 = customerDao.insert(new Customer("Three", "C", Date.valueOf("1860-12-10")));

        return null;
    }
}
}
```

Firstly I thought it was because my app was not running so it meant my database was closed but that was not the case. I had my app open while testing.

Secondly - when I check if the database is open after i instantiate my database (`db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, ShopDatabase.class).build();`) -  `db.isOpen()` -> it returns **false** every time.

What can cause the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when I check if the database is open after i instantiate my database (`db = Room.inMemoryDatabaseBuilder(context, ShopDatabase.class).build();`) - db.isOpen() -> it returns false every time.

The database is not opened until you attempt to access it. You can force accessing it (getting a Writable or Readable database/connection aka opening the database file itself which is all done behind the scenes on your behalf) before you return the instance. e.g.

```
......
instance.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
return instance;
```

## Example

using :-

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    shopDatabase = ShopDatabase.getInstance(this);
    boolean dbopen = shopDatabase.isOpen();
    if (dbopen); //<<<<<<<<<< breakpoint here

}
```

With :-

```
public static synchronized ShopDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                ShopDatabase.class,"shop_database")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .addCallback(roomCallback)
                .build();
    }
    //instance.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
    return instance;
}
```

results in

[image]

changing to use :-

```
public static synchronized ShopDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                ShopDatabase.class,"shop_database")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .addCallback(roomCallback)
                .build();
    }
    instance.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase(); //<<<<<<<<< ADDED
    return instance;
}
```

results in :-

[image]

> I could NOT insert data in the Main Thread

You can if you add `.allowMainThreadQueries()` when building

e.g.

```
public static synchronized ShopDatabase getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = Room.databaseBuilder(context.getApplicationContext(),
                ShopDatabase.class,"shop_database")
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .addCallback(roomCallback)
                .build();
    }
    instance.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();
    return instance;
}
```

- You may wish to not use this though.

Comment: First of my mistakes were that, since this is my first time testing UI in Android, i ran my test in src/test instead of src/androidTest. 

Later on i managed to open my database with your method `.instance.getOpenHelper().getWritableDatabase();` and it did work BUT i ran into other complications that i will not go into details with. 

I managed to insert AND test my data using `.allowMainThreadQueries()` - but can you tell me why this is wrong when im not interacting with my application when testing anyway so it should not be a concern if the Main thread is occupied or not? Thank you.

Comment: @Delice main thread is virtually always occupied (somewhat) as it's basically a loop checking to see see if anything is being done (Intents being issued I believe). I've rarely had any issues but if you are publishing an App you don't want an [ANR](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr) as you may then get bad ratings *(p.s. using room rather than SQLite directly incurrs overheads (was looking into this but that's on the shelf at present I believe something like 16% overhead using room))*.

Comment: In the testing environment, the app is not even active so it means that there can be no user inputs or any other kind of UI-interactions - thats why i added the `.allowMainThreadQueries()` in my test.class instead of where i create my database. Correct me of im still wrong in this